# material progress bar doesn't work with *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to display a progress bar for processing event, So I used the material progress bar with angular condition `*ngIf`. It's not showing at first when I click a button to process the event but when I refresh the browser it shows.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
   (click)="scan()">CLICK
</button>

<div *ngIf="isScanning" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate"></div>
```

**ts file**

```
scan() {
        this.isScanning = true;
    }
```

The problem I have is progress bar is working but it's not working with the `*ngIf` but if I reload the page after I press the button the progress bar is showing. I couldn't figure out what is happing here. Any help?

Comment: any console error?while press CLICK button

Comment: Nop, there is no errors.

Comment: Can you add a complete template example? Where is your <mat-progress-bar> component ? Btw as Shailesh Ladumor pointed out, all material component us onPush change detection strategy. So if no input is changed the template will no be refresh.

Answer (score 2):

add this into your component and try

```
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
}

scan() {
        this.isScanning = true;
       this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your component when you are defining the ngModel

```html
export class yourTsclassname {
   
isScanning:any=false;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
```